# Zend_Queue database scheme

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-queue

I'm using Zend_Queue to queue and send out emails (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.queue.adapters.html)

Is there a way to modify the Zend_Queue_Adapter_Db default table names? 
By default, the table names are "queue" & "message" which are a little confusing and I would like to name them queues and queues_messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those table names appear to be hardcoded as default property values with no built-in mutators, but you can probably override Zend_Queue_Adapter_Db to do your bidding. This code is untested, but something like the following:

```
class My_Queue_Adapter_Db extends Zend_Queue_Adapter_Db
{
    public function __construct($options, Zend_Queue $queue = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($options, $queue);
        if (isset($options['queueTableName']) {
            $this->_queueTable->setOptions(
                array(Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::NAME => $options['queueTableName'])
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Then just pass a 'queueTableName' property to the constructor. Same principles applies to the _messageTable property.